# Receiving XML Posted data

Tags: 8

I have a question about what would be the best way for a module to accept a posted XML file via a web service.  What I am trying to do is receive the file, read through the contents of the file, and update a setting on my site via the contents of the file. Could some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: What does "posted", mean in this context?

Comment: OH sorry, "posted," means that if I want to POST a file via web service to my Drupal site I would be able to recieve this file and parse it through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the cURL solution.

```
//login curl
$crl = curl_init();
$url = "http://************.localhost:8080/user/login";
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//Drupal login credentials
$postdata = array(
  "name" => "restuser", 
  "passw" => "*******",
  "form_id" => "user_login", 
  "op" => "Log in",
);

//Tell cURL to use post data
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

$result = curl_exec($crl);
$header_code = curl_getinfo($crl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($header_code != 200) {
    die("Cannot login.");
    echo 'Connection Died';
}else{
       if (file_exists('order.xml')) {
            $xml_data_before_encode = simplexml_load_file('order.xml');
            $xml_data_post_data = preparePostFields($xml_data_before_encode) ;

            $URL = 'http://*******.localhost:8080/users/restuser/12345';
            $crl = curl_init($URL);
            curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
            curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data_post_data");
            curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            echo $output = curl_exec($crl);
            curl_close($crl);
       }else{
            print 'Second cURL request did not fire.';
       }
```

}
   function preparePostFields($array) {

```
  $params = array();

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $params[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
  }
  return implode('&', $params);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something I've tried myself, but if you create a form with a [file](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#file) element, you should be able to control the $_POST['id'] that Drupal looks for by manipulating the id of the file-element.

That way the file should get passed on to the forms submit function, and then you can do whatever you want with it's content and react accordingly afterwards.

Comment: Hello Letharion, thank you for the advice.  A very interesting idea.  I will give it a try and let you know of my outcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Cool, I look forward to hearing how it works out.

Comment: Hello Letharion, I ended up taking a different approach to answer my question.  Instead of posting a file, I parsed the XML file into a "postable" string and used cURL to hit a users route in Drupal, log the user in, and post that data to the module I had waiting for my post data on the other side.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. :) Please post your solution as an answer, and accept it, so the question get's removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used it for your exact situation, you should take a look at the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module.  The module is rather well documented, and has examples.  Creating an endpoint and wiring up your callbacks should be fairly easy.

Comment: This is good module to keep in mind, I had trouble installing it though because Drupal kept telling me I was missing the OAuth module, I tried installing it and it would not install properly?  I ended up taking a different approach posting data with cURL though.